# What is the best way to insert data first time into the application tables from other source?

Tags: database, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I require to fetch data from other source using REST api calls only one time at the time of deploying my application. What can be the best possible way for doing this ?

I am relatively new in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Below are some ways.

1. use @PostConstruct on method and scope of bean is singleton so whenever bean is getting created while application loading it will invoke rest point.
2. use commandliner interface of spring
3. use kubernetes job.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I have some doubts on the suggestion...
How can PostConstruct can help here ? PostConstruct run after the bean creation right ? then how can one will identify that in which bean class's PostConstruct should call the REST api ?

Also, instead of this can SpringRunner will help ?

Comment: you can define the bean which explicitly does the call to rest endpoint and annotate that method with Postconstruct so it will get invoked only once. Like Class FetchRestData{ '@'PostContruct public void fetchData(){ //business logic}}